# bootrap Overlaytrigger tooltip is not showing in table data field

Tags: tooltip, overlay

```
<OverlayTrigger
            placement={"top"}
            overlay={
              <Tooltip id="popover-contained">
                ruchi verma
              </Tooltip>
            }>
            <span className="max-w-[105px] whitespace-nowrap text-ellipsis overflow-hidden inline-block text-black">
              {formatDate(row.cell.value)}
            </span>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

tooltip is not showing in table data field.

I tried to fix using z-index:9 but that was not working in .tooltip but in browser this was working.